# How can I group by regex value of a column in jQgrid?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a column in a grid called `URL`, what I want to do is to group this column by a regex value, I want to group for ex: http://www.amazon.com/some_link and www.amazon.com/another_link, and another group for http://www.ebay.com/some_link with www.ebay.com/another_one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but I guess you could extract the domain ("amazon.com", "ebay.com") to a hidden column and group by that.